# Ubuntu takes so long to get to Login screen

Tags: boot, 17.04

I have installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my spare SSD and everything went smoothly but when starting up, it takes forever to get to the Login Screen.

I saw [Ubuntu Desktop 17.04 64bit slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905031/ubuntu-desktop-17-04-64bit-slow-boot) and I too have the encryption enabled but I don't understand the answer in it. I checked the links provided but I don't think there's a solution in them.

Comment: Since you cannot comment there, I commented and asked him for more detail on the workflow.

Comment: What's your question?