# Ubuntu 17.04 Long boot time due to intel-vbtn

Tags: boot, 17.04

Just installed Ubuntu 17.04 today on my Spectre x360 laptop, but its taking about 2 minutes to boot (Windows took ~10 seconds).

As suggested here: [How to fix very slow Ubuntu booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35497/how-to-fix-very-slow-ubuntu-booting)
I ran the `dmesg` command, here is an excerpt of the output where I believe the problem is:

```
[    5.771049] audit: type=1400 audit(1492997122.163:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=747 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.772152] audit: type=1400 audit(1492997122.163:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=751 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.773675] audit: type=1400 audit(1492997122.163:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=752 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.773677] audit: type=1400 audit(1492997122.163:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=752 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.086226] intel-vbtn INT33D6:00: unknown event index 0xcd
[   28.153199] intel-vbtn INT33D6:00: unknown event index 0xcd
[   95.264415] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   95.264417] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   95.264420] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   95.331589] haswell-pcm-audio haswell-pcm-audio: FW loaded, mailbox readback FW info: type 01, - version: 00.00, build 77, source commit id: 876ac6906f31a43b6772b23c7c983ce9dcb18a19
[   95.429468] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[   95.431987] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   95.432503] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   95.497193] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   95.497668] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   95.522825] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[   95.531535] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   95.531986] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   95.604347] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

I really wasn't able to find much on what `intel-vbtn INT33D6:00: unknown event index 0xcd` is or how to fix it so any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

As mentioned in the comments, if you have an encrypted home, Ubiquity still creates a cryptoswap partition instead of linking to the swapfile.

This can be fixed by following this guide:

[Ubuntu Desktop 17.04 64bit slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905031/ubuntu-desktop-17-04-64bit-slow-boot)

## Original Workaround

First off I want to clarify that I have the same issue and so I want to give some further details on the hardware (for all those who might be able to debug the error):

- HP Spectre x360 15-bl002ng
- Intel i7-7500U
- Nvidia 940MX
- NVME PCIe SSD (Samsung I believe)

Second:

I found a workaround by setting the systemd timeout to 10s instead of 90s. To do so, edit `/etc/systemd/system.conf`. In my case I had to uncomment the following two lines set the timer:

```
DefaultTimeoutStartSec=10s
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=10s
```

After a reboot, the system is up after about 10 seconds. May be warned however, that such a low timeout may cause other, more severe problems. So do that at your own risk!

Third:

For all those who can actually figure out what might be wrong I would like to add what I found out:

After I upgraded to kernel 4.11 RC8 (to fix `intel-vbtn INT33D6:00: unknown event index 0xcd`, [comment #24](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1629415)) I got way more debug info and so noticed that the boot sequence is actually stuck at `A start job is running for [some dev + UUID presumably]`.

I stumbled across a [German Debian forum](https://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=151997) where the error seems to be caused by a mismatch of the actually UUID of the swap partition reported by `sudo blkid` and the used UUID by `fstab`.

However, since 17.04 Ubuntu uses a swapfile instead of a partition, I am clueless on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Do you have an encrypted home partition? Then it could potentially be this bug https://askubuntu.com/questions/905031/ubuntu-desktop-17-04-64bit-slow-boot

Comment: I actually do have an encrypted home, so thanks a lot! I also updated the answer to include the link