# Ubuntu 17.04 Randomly Freezes

Tags: crash

Today I upgraded from Ubuntu 16 to 17.  Everything worked fine until I left my computer on for about 2-3 hours. Then it crashed, except there were no error screen or message.  Just the last image that happened before it crashed. The mouse won't move, keyboard doesn't work, and all the operations(My download stopped... I don't exactly know if everything does) don't continue.  I just thought it was a random issue and carried on by powering off my machine manually, but it occurred again and I don't think this is just something to ignore. Any help would be nice for how to fix this as I have no idea. Also I am using Ubuntu desktop.

Update:
The output of `ls -alt /var/crash` is

> total 8
>   drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Apr 11 21:21 ..
>   drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Apr 11 21:14 .

```
dpkg -l intel-microcode
```

Gives me the error

> dpkg-query: no packages found matching intel-microcode

```
Free -h
```

> ```
>           total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
> ```
>
> Mem:           7.7G        1.8G        349M        101M        5.6G        5.5G
>   Swap:            0B          0B          0B

and `swapon` gives no output.

Next update:

```
cat /etc/fstab #If there was a hashtag at the start of a line it got bolded.

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.  
#  
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a  
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices  
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).  
#  
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>  
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation  
UUID=8eedf4cb-b322-4455-905b-  c50264691a4d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0  1  
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0   
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

and here is my Gparted screenshot.

[image: My Gparted Screenshot]

**Next Update:**
Output of `sudo blkid`  (PARTUUID is on the same line its just it didn't come out that way on this)

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="8eedf4cb-b322-4455-905b-c50264691a4d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="46d95458-01"  
/dev/sda5: UUID="4e48c05f-02d1-47ef-9a5f-bb8cba50dd2b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="46d95458-05"  
/dev/sda6: UUID="7f7d6675-31a4-4100-9d32-5faa0e0cea3e" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="46d95458-06"  
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="HD-LXU3" UUID="F45A29EB5A29AB76" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="aa1e0d10-01"
```

Output of `ls -al /`
total 2097264
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root       4096 May 26 12:10 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root       4096 May 26 12:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 May 27 23:15 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root       4096 May 29 13:09 boot
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root       4096 May 26 11:44 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root       4480 Jun  4 12:00 dev
drwxr-xr-x 140 root root      12288 Jun  2 17:36 etc
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root       4096 May 26 11:47 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         33 May 26 12:10 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-21-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         33 May 26 11:50 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-19-generic
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root       4096 May 26 13:03 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Apr 11 21:07 lib64
drwx------   2 root root      16384 May 26 11:43 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root       4096 May 26 11:56 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Apr 11 21:07 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root       4096 May 28 09:51 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 242 root root          0 Jun  4 11:58 proc
drwx------   4 root root       4096 May 29 21:03 root
drwxr-xr-x  30 root root        960 Jun  4 12:05 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root      12288 May 27 23:15 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Apr  6 02:32 snap
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Apr 11 21:07 srv
-rw-------   1 root root 2147483648 May 26 11:44 swapfile
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root          0 Jun  4 13:43 sys
drwxrwxrwt  16 root root       4096 Jun  4 13:46 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root       4096 Apr 11 21:13 usr
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root       4096 May 28 14:08 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         30 May 26 12:10 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-21-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         30 May 26 11:50 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-19-generic

## Final Edits

`free -h` gives me:

```
>               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        889M        6.2G         46M        692M        6.6G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
```

`swapon` gives:

```
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO

> /dev/dm-0 partition   2G   0B   -1
```

And `ls -alh /swapfile` gives:

> -rw------- 1 root root 2.0G Jun  4 21:41 /swapfile

Also my startup time has increased tremulously.

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `ls -alt /var/crash` and we can start there. Do you have "Bay Trail" Intel CPU's?

Comment: @NonnyMoose your request for system logs really is hard to do... do you know how large those files can get? And, even if they could post them, are you going to read through all of that text?

Comment: This is my CPU and I do not think it is Bay Trail.  https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i5-4690+%40+3.50GHz#history

Comment: Never mind, @heynnema is right.

Comment: Since there wasn't anything in /var/crash, and no crash log on your screen, it looks like you have a **freeze** condition, not a crash condition (edit your question's title please). Show me `dpkg -l intel-microcode` and `free -h` and `swapon` (edit that into your question again). For comments directed to me, please start them with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: If you have Intel processors, then install `intel-microcode`. You have no swapfile/swap partition. Was that an intentional decision? Show me `cat /etc/fstab` and a current-window-only screenshot of `gparted`.

Comment: When you make an update, or need to communicate with me directly, start a new comment with `@heynnema` or I may miss it. You went to 17.04 as an **upgrade**, not a **new fresh** install, yes? I see 3 different swap configurations. Show me `ls -al /` and `sudo blkid` and show me the full `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: @heynnema Updated and I did go to Ubuntu 17 as an upgrade from 16.  Also I am dual-booted with another Debian Linux if that makes any difference.

Comment: Please see my answer below. When you're done, and have successfully rebooted, show me the `terminal` output of `free -h` and `swapon` and `ls -alh /swapfile`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be problems with 17.04 and encrypted swapfiles... and there are some workarounds...

Edit your `/etc/crypttab` like so:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/crypttab
```

Change this line:

```
cryptswap1 UUID=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

To this:

```
cryptswap1 /swapfile /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

Also make sure that your `/etc/fstab` contains this:

```
/swapfile               none  swap  sw  0  0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

References:

[Ubuntu Desktop 17.04 64bit slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905031/ubuntu-desktop-17-04-64bit-slow-boot/906340#906340)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1668535

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1670336

Comment: Updated under Final Edits and my startup time increased... guessing thats a good sign

Comment: @Peyto Startup time **increased**? From what to what? Maybe you mean **decreased**... as in faster?

Comment: Yes sorry I entered that in wrong.  Also it hasn't frozen since so I'm accepting your answer.