# Debugging Ubuntu 17.04 server freeze?

Tags: server, 17.04, crash, debugging

I'm a novice at Ubuntu and my server is occasionally locking up. It's not while I'm doing anything in particular so it's difficult for me to figure know where to start.

I'm more familiar with debugging MacOS so I was hoping someone could point me at where to start? Are there crash logs I can find or is that sort of system monitoring not set up by default? If that's the case what do I need to do to set it up?

My current theory is simply that it's Ryzen instability (I need to do a bios update) but I have nothing to go on for that other than guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a good idea to eliminate the BIOS as a problem source especially if you are doing any overclocking.  Specifically memory overclocking.  You might also want to run memtest since issues there can cause intermittent, difficult to repeat freezes and crashes.

If you like logs, you are going to love Linux.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles

The most likely place to find something interesting is /var/log/syslog

If the system is freezing, have a terminal open running the command

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Whatever is in the last log entry would be a pretty good clue on where to start looking, especially if every time the machine freezes, the same messages show up.

You'd also probably want to disable any apps that are not part of the stable distribution set until you get it all sorted out..

There are also a few bugs in 17.04.  Here's one that may effect you

[Ubuntu 17.04 Randomly Freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919285/ubuntu-17-04-randomly-freezes?rq=1)

If stability is important to you, 16.04 LTS is a really stable release.

Comment: Stability isn't a major issue. It's a personal server and aside from media duties it's more of a playground than anything. It just keeps happening and I do love a good mystery. These are great starting points for me. Thanks!