# Ubuntu 17.04 Bootup / on SSD but slow

Tags: boot, ssd

I have the following output and my ubuntu boots very slowly. it takes like 2-3 minutes to boot up where was windows only takes like 15 seconds. Here the output of journalctl:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24706296/

It would be nice if someone could help me as i'd really like to boot fast into ubuntu.

I have everything on SSD (/) but only /var and /home on hdd.

Edit:

sudo blkid:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Wiederherstellung" UUID="1E5EB9035EB8D4AD" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="daad9650-8cde-491d-80db-7dda8e1874c0"
/dev/sda2: UUID="56B9-5488" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="419f5006-cb88-4fcc-9b5e-39ca6d657edb"
/dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="e924079c-0c0c-4157-b82d-85f0a8ef5e8c"
/dev/sda4: UUID="6862CAA762CA78F8" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="4c2eb33b-8ea1-4c7e-9c72-25c490d407ce"
/dev/sda5: UUID="76A07C5BA07C2431" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="887bbacf-c0e9-44b0-bf46-1385b114068b"
/dev/sda6: UUID="c89b4926-af5a-416a-b61a-006aaa34a3cc" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="abab0c8d-8d6e-4529-8d94-1a88d0900861"
/dev/sda7: UUID="69152b87-29d1-410d-a49b-b31e1e9885f4" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="7d94acf0-a66c-44d4-ba94-d3cd4ca6a31b"
/dev/sdb1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="bdc2d24e-e974-441f-b190-b8b285579f87"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Volume" UUID="1A4A64574A643225" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="ec522179-fc5b-4406-a029-1036e2e1df7c"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="da267417-9a48-45a2-a3e2-2bc62163003a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8c1e23df-5f97-44f8-a344-3fb713b13bf6"
/dev/sdb4: UUID="f2362bd0-5a3d-4e0f-b915-d7ab299d0be9" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c85406d4-71fc-46f6-a9c4-a4f76b2cc185"
```

cat /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=c89b4926-af5a-416a-b61a-006aaa34a3cc /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=56B9-5488  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb4 during installation
UUID=f2362bd0-5a3d-4e0f-b915-d7ab299d0be9 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /var was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=da267417-9a48-45a2-a3e2-2bc62163003a /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

free -h:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,7G        2,8G        121M         92M        4,8G        4,5G
Swap:          7,8G          0B        7,8G
```

uwe@loopy-ubuntu:~$ swapon

```
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sda7 partition 7,8G   0B   -1
```

uwe@loopy-ubuntu:~$ ls -al /

```
total 1541232
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root       4096 Mai 29 08:00 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root       4096 Mai 29 08:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Mai 29 08:00 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root       4096 Mai 29 00:07 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Mai 28 23:02 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root       4480 Mai 30 11:52 dev
drwxr-xr-x 139 root root      12288 Mai 29 21:38 etc
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root       4096 Mai 28 23:02 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         33 Mai 29 00:04 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-22-generic
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root       4096 Mai 29 00:24 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Mai 29 00:06 lib32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Apr 12 05:06 lib64
drwx------   2 root root      16384 Mai 28 22:51 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root       4096 Mai 29 08:00 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Apr 12 05:06 mnt
dr-xr-xr-x 325 root root          0 Mai 30 11:50 proc
drwx------   3 root root       4096 Apr 12 05:17 root
drwxr-xr-x  30 root root        940 Mai 30 11:56 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root      12288 Mai 29 00:06 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Apr  6 10:32 snap
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Apr 12 05:06 srv
-rw-------   1 root root 1578106880 Mai 28 23:01 swapfile
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root          0 Mai 30 11:58 sys
drwxrwxrwt  19 root root       4096 Mai 30 11:56 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root       4096 Mai 29 00:06 usr
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root       4096 Apr 12 05:18 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         30 Mai 29 00:04 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-22-generic
```

New ls -alh /swapfile:

-rw------- 1 root root 4,0G Mai 30 22:40 /swapfile

uwe@loopy-ubuntu:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,7G        3,7G        1,3G        129M        2,8G        3,7G
Swap:          4,0G          0B        4,0G

journalctl:
uwe@loopy-ubuntu:~$ journalctl --boot | pastebinit
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24737809/

I created the swapfile myself.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24737883/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Partial answer... work in progress...

**Step 1:**

**You may have some disk corruption on your SSD.**

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Step #2: DON'T DO THIS UNTIL I TELL YOU TO**

Now we **begin** to fix your /swapfile problem.

Edit your `/etc/fstab`...

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Change this line:

```
/swapfile   none   swap    sw              0       0
```

To this:

```
#/swapfile   none   swap    sw              0       0
```

Save the file and quit gedit.

Reboot and note if there's a boot time improvement.

**More pending...**

If boot times improved... delete /swapfile...

Create a swap partition or swapfile on /dev/sdb...

Edit /etc/fstab...

Delete /dev/sda7 swap partition...

**Step #3:**

There seems to be problems with 17.04 and encrypted swapfiles... and there are some workarounds...

Edit your `/etc/crypttab` like so:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/crypttab
```

Change this line:

```
cryptswap1 UUID=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

To this:

```
cryptswap1 /swapfile /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

Also make sure that your `/etc/fstab` contains this:

```
/swapfile               none  swap  sw  0  0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

References:

[Ubuntu Desktop 17.04 64bit slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905031/ubuntu-desktop-17-04-64bit-slow-boot/906340#906340)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1668535

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1670336

Comment: I've completeley reinstalled before I read your answer. It didn't help my bootup still takes long. I've set up a completely new swapfile, now the swap works. After reboot I have 4GBs of swap. Anyway, I did what u said, scan my filesystem for errors, but i didnt get anything. What I got was some error about cryptswap. Because I set my home folder to be encrypted. Heres a picture of everything: https://goo.gl/photos/p6MwdPBJjNEXt9Cq6

Comment: ive tried commenting /swapfile in /etc/fstab but it didnt help. it still loads that long. one thing. when the system boots up, for a really short time it displays some text but it goes away too fast i cant read it. is it possible that my system scans something every time on boot up?

Comment: I only wanted to comment out your original /swapfile because it was causing problems. It was sized incorrectly, and probably didn't have `mkswap` performed on it, and your journal log showed the problem. Since you've reinstalled, the /swapfile is probably fine, so commenting it out now won't make any boot difference, unless you have the same problem as before. You will still want to relocate /swapfile to the SSD. The message that you briefly see is fsck telling you that the file system is clean.

Comment: this helped. thank you very much my system boots within 5 seconds now! :)