# Ubuntu 17.04 Freezing Issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, freeze

Otherwise stable Ubuntu machine have an issue since installing that is critical freezing without apparent reasons. There are high probabilities that the issue been caused by NVDIA videocard.

- [complete technical specs of the PC in question](https://0bin.net/paste/S0lh8aU4I+UTBYde#0kR1JT9Emm9Qyubd-vD7bvyDmd+b4ldCNNDHzCorUco)
- [example of syslog at the moment of the crash](https://0bin.net/paste/ElOOMelH7hN7U1xX#q89m3sSv9Qpnsy4DPFJAudgCHLew4C9hfrfDqWVKaLU)

`sudo blkid` output:

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="0E5C95E45C95C73D" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="1ef0523b-02"
/dev/sda5: UUID="16EA-1372" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="1ef0523b-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="fe90c52c-c1b7-4845-971e-e7ed5cb45ac4" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1ef0523b-06"
```

`/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=fe90c52c-c1b7-4845-971e-e7ed5cb45ac4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

`/etc/crypttab`:

```
cryptswap1 UUID=f09a516a-22c0-475c-b749-31ffed5c7bda /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

`ls -alh /swapfile`:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 2.0G May  3 13:31 /swapfile
```

Comment: How new is the hardware?

Comment: Pretty recent, if you can tell me how to send this data I would do it.

Comment: Please use `hardinfo` and then take a screenshot of the program. IF it's not installed, run `sudo apt install hardinfo` first.

Comment: https://0bin.net/paste/6vQNtb8lg7QXeVnu#j3XMyLMAZatGr4wy6xAk6B3+Sw4flvDIMylWncnNWBz - this is a screenshot of the complete settings from hardinfo, as I was not clear which data you need exactly I decide to take them all.

Comment: @paravosky it's unreadable. I don't know if it's your fault or not, but it looks like garbled pixels.

Comment: @MarkYisri here it is in text format: https://0bin.net/paste/ekvHRTCyINZ+J-EX#bz3T+26vI+3PnTFfCHfYcJspd0flNS6y84VaAMO7znZ

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/crypttab` and `ls -alh /swapfile` and I'll take a look. Also see my premature answer.

Comment: @heynnema I updated my question with info requested, although it appears the issue was that the nvdia drivers wasn't been installed. system didn't hang for suspicious amount of time =)

Comment: In looking at your updates, it looks like you do have the encrypted /swapfile problem that my answer addresses. Please follow the instructions there. I doubt that missing nvidia drivers would have caused the freezes. Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I changed what you said.  Should I also do >Also make sure that your /etc/fstab contains this:

/swapfile               none  swap  sw  0  0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1  none  swap  sw  0  0
My terminal returns sudo: /etc/fstab: command not found
Also, any way to stress test this?

Comment: The correct command is `gksudo gedit {filename to edit}`. Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be problems with 17.04 and encrypted swapfiles... and there are some workarounds...

Edit your `/etc/crypttab` like so:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/crypttab
```

Change this line:

```
cryptswap1 UUID=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

To this:

```
cryptswap1 /swapfile /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

Also make sure that your `/etc/fstab` contains this:

```
/swapfile               none  swap  sw  0  0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

References:

[Ubuntu Desktop 17.04 64bit slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905031/ubuntu-desktop-17-04-64bit-slow-boot/906340#906340)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1668535

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1670336

Comment: There seems to be a problem now related to solution you proposed. My system stop loading, after the boot it sends me to initramfs. I am almost sure it is not a hard disk crash, as mentioned in a numeral manuals around the web, the issue - I suspect - might be in that I didn't achieve to change /etc/fstab options as you mentioned. Any way you can help me to diagnose what the problem is? Keep in mind that the drive is encrypted.

Comment: The system worked after the fix, yes? Sounds like you've got a new problem. Are you able to get to the GRUB menu, and recovery mode? Do you have access to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: yes, to everything.

Comment: Start a new question for me. Ping me in a comment starting with `@heynnema` and I'll try and help you.