# Really slow boot Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: boot, 17.04, swap

I just fixed dual-boot on my laptop. Win10 and Ubuntu 17.04. Everything went fine, but the boot time is horrible on Ubuntu. Win10 is just a few seconds (using a regular SSD) but Ubuntu is a couple of minutes.

I have googled the issue and found a few answers pointing out some "swap disk" thing. But since I am a total newbie I have no idea what they are talking about and therefore I would like some newbie-help.

I would love some help, thanks!

I don't know if this helps, but this is my /etc/fstab/:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=13a0e086-eafd-46e0-8776-a980a45eb32a /               ext4    errors=remoun$
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=AE44-EFFB  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw           $
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: You are comparing Windows restore from a hibernation and Ubuntu boot. Try to reboot Windows, not shutdown, and you will see how "fast" it really boots. Or disable "Fast Boot" that is hibernation instead of shutdown. But a couple of minutes is really slow to boot from SSD.

Answer (score 1):

Also check your `/etc/crypttab`.  If it points to a UUID rather than a file location in 17.04, this will need to be updated.  My boot times went from minutes to under 15 seconds.  See [Ubuntu Desktop 17.04 64-bit with encrypted home, slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905031/ubuntu-desktop-17-04-64-bit-with-encrypted-home-slow-boot)